# How can I check if the pane is in log scale?

Tags: pine-script, indicator

I have a script with different indicators but some may only show if pane is in log scale.
Is their a way to check this with pine script?

Comment: Additional details will make it easier for someone to provide a helpful answer. Check out [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some great tips.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to do so. Chart settings, drawings, toolbar tools etc are not accessible via pine

Comment: bummer.. Thx for the info!