# Pinescript/Trading View - plot indicator pane on log scale only if price is on log scale

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Two related questions...

I'm working on an indicator that plots to its own pane, and must be plotted on the same scale type (log vs linear) as the main price chart. **1) Is there a TradingView feature that allows the user to select log scale on the indicator pane (as opposed to the price chart)?.**

Assuming the above functionality does not exist (and even if it does), the preferred solution would be to write the script such that the indicator detects the scale on the price chart plot and automatically decides whether to plot log or linear based on the state of the main price chart. Toggling between log and linear should be easy to accomplish.  **2) So, does anybody know if there is a way for pinescript to "detect" the current scale on the price chart?**

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to check whether the scale is log or not from Pine Script.
(was asked before several times, e.g. [How can I check if the pane is in log scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69551716/how-can-i-check-if-the-pane-is-in-log-scale))

You can select the type of the scale on every indicator pane of the chart independently from the main chart and/or the other indicator panes. Just right-click on the scale and choose the type you wish.

Comment: Thanks....didn't realize the y-axis on the indicator pane was independent of the one on the price chart